# Packaging a jar into a dist dir with separated external resources and dependencies

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, dependencies

Here's what I'm trying to achieve - a `dist` directory (or a zip file) that looks like this:

```
dist/
|-- application-1.0.jar
|-- conf/
    |-- application.properties
    |-- log4j.properties
|-- lib/
    |-- *.jar
```

Basically:

- An executable jar is produced (with appropriate classpath in the manifest)
- I want to exclude `src/main/resources` from being automatically packaged with the jar, so that `application.properties` can be modified
- I want to have external dependencies in the `lib/` directory

I came up with a solution using a profile with plugins attached to the package phase, but would using the assembly plugin be a better solution?

Answer (score 11):

The solution using the assembly plugin has a few parts:

- The pom includes configuring the jar plugin (`maven-jar-plugin`), and configuring the assembly plugin (`maven-assembly-plugin`).
- During maven's packaging phase, the jar plugin is called to construct the application jar.
- Then the assembly plugin is run, and combines the constructed jar, resources and dependencies into a zip file as defined by the assembly file (`distribution-zip.xml`).

In the pom, configure the plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <!-- Make an executable jar, adjust classpath entries-->
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.acme.KillerApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <!--Resources will be placed under conf/-->
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>./conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!--exclude the properties file from the archive-->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly/distribution-zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
```

The contents of the assembly file `distribution-zip.xml` (with thanks to [Neeme Praks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200695/packaging-a-jar-into-a-dist-dir-with-separated-external-resources-and-dependencie/4200734#4200734)) combines the created jar, resources and dependencies:

```
<assembly>
    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <!--Include runtime dependencies-->
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get the generated application jar-->
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get application resources-->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get misc user files-->
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>       
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The resulting distributable zip file is created like `target/killer-app-1.0-dist.zip`!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use two plugins to accomplish this: **maven-jar-plugin** and **maven-assembly-plugin**.

Useful `pom.xml` samples:

- [how make JAR executable and set manifest classpath](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)
- [how to exclude files from JAR file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html)
- [assembly plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

(I would recommend you to separate the user-editable properties files to separate directory, but it is a matter of taste.)

Sample assembly configuration, to get you started:

```
<assembly>
  <id>dist</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  <baseDirectory>dist</baseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/run</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.sh</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>src/run/run.sh</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Cool, but also need to make the jar executable, set the manifest classpath, and exclude the properties file from the jar..

Comment: that is already a matter of configuring your JAR plugin, nothing to do with assembly plugin. I guess you are already doing that, no? And it would help if you would add relevant sections from your pom.xml to your question.

Comment: make JAR executable and set manifest classpath: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html, exclude properties: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html