# Maven, exclude folder of resources from packaged jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to achieve the following distribution for my application, and I'm following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200695/packaging-a-jar-into-a-dist-dir-with-separated-external-resources-and-dependenci) as guideline

```
dist/
|-- application-1.0.jar
|-- conf/
    |-- application.properties
    |-- log4j.properties
|-- lib/
    |-- *.jar
```

My `src/main/resources` looks like following

```
resources/
|-- to.be.packaged.inside.jar
|-- to.be.packaged/
|   |-- also
|-- conf/
    |-- application.properties
    |-- log4j.properties
```

Now, I want to exclude the whole *conf* folder from being packaged in the JAR (but placed in the target folder).

I tried the following configuration to *maven-jar-plugin*

```
<excludes>
  <exclude>conf/*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

However, this still packages *an empty conf folder* inside the JAR. How do I exclude *the folder and the content*?

Answer (score 3):

With `conf/*` you're only excluding the matching files, it doesn't match the `conf` directory. By added `<exclude>conf</exclude>` the directory will be excluded as well.

However, you should ask yourself: should these files be available on the classpath? I would expect the conf-directory to be a directory in the project-root (i.e. `<project-root>/conf` ), which also means a cleaner pom because you don't have to exclude resources.

Comment: I tried only `conf`, but in that case nothing was excluded. And what do you mean by the cleaner pom?

Comment: Be aware that ALL directories and files are evaluated, so only conf is not enough.`conf/application.properties` doesn't match the exclude-pattern, so it is included.
WRT the cleaner pom, you don't have to add custom configuration. Sure, it is only a couple of lines, but by moving the conf-folder the configuration is also isolated from the classpath, which is a good thing when thinking of externalizing configuration.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen what the answer ment is that you need to add the second exclude in addition to the existing one. So you will have 2 exclude items: `<exclude>conf/*</exclude>` and `<exclude>conf</exclude>`