# Package resource files outside of JAR file with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a standard java application that I'm building with Maven. It includes a few files under src/main/resource directory. At present, those files are being packaged inside the JAR fiel that is produced, which I would expect, but is there a way to configure the maven assembly plugin to package those files outside of the JAR file, or can I achieve that with another plugin (resources?)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200695/packaging-a-jar-into-a-dist-dir-with-separated-external-resources-and-dependenci should solve your question

Comment: Why do you use the maven-assembly-plugin? For which purpose?

Comment: My understanding is that it assists with customizing the structure and organization of the artifacts that come out the build process